# Column does not exists in datasouruce problem when binding SubSonic collection to dropdown

Tags: asp.net, subsonic, data-access-layer

I've a table with Primary Key with _ (underscore) in its name like: User_Id. When SubSonic generates DAL it removes underscores. Now I'm binding the object collection to DropDownList like follows:

```
private void LoadCbo()
{
    UserCollection users=(new UserCollection()).Load();
    User u=new User(){
        UserId=-1,
        Name="[Select]"};
   users.Insert(0,u);

   ddlUsers.DataSource=users;
   ddlUsers.DataValueField=User.Columns.UserId;
   ddlUsers.DataTextField=User.Columns.Name;
   ddUsers.DataBind();    
}
```

On running it tells me that object does not contains column with name "User_Id".

PS:- using "UserId" works fine. I just want to know if this is a bug in SubSonic (2.1) or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SubSonic 2.2, you can also do this:

```
ddlUsers.DataValueField = User.UserIdColumn.PropertyName;
```

This way you can avoid hardcoding column names in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The Columns collection is made up of the column names in the database, not the property names of the object. This isn't a bug it's an essential piece of functionality otherwise SubSonic would have no knowledge of how to query the actual database.

The following line is specifying what property to use when populating the value of the dropdown:

```
ddlUsers.DataValueField=User.Columns.UserId;
```

The value of User.Columns.UserId will be "User_Id", it is the name of the column in your database table, not the name of the property. However when ddlUsers is databinding it cannot find a property of the User object with the name User_Id because when SubSonic generates your DAL it removes the underscore from the property name. The best fix is (as pointed out by ranomore):

```
ddlUsers.DataValueField = User.UserIdColumn.PropertyName;
```

Comment: @adam please pay attention to ps. "I just want to know if this is a bug in SubSonic (2.1) or I'm doing something wrong"
what you suggest is written it in question. I already know that specifying column name as string ("UserId") does the trick. As I'm binding to User object (not row from database) the Columns.UserId should return the name as it is in the properties of the object not what is uses to fetch and push values to database. If SubSonic is modifying column names it should take care to give modified names to outside object and use the names from table for talking with DB.

Comment: I've clarified my answer to hopefully make it more obvious. The Columns collection is there specifically for talking with the DB so it has to return the DB name not the property name. By using it to specify the databinding properties you are doing something wrong.

Comment: The answer to the question in the PS is: "This is NOT a bug in SubSonic. You are doing something wrong."